# SQL insert using Excel file

Tags: sql, excel, firebird

In my Firebird database, I have a `Table_Product` which stores many individual numbered tables, for example:

```
   TBID PRODUCT  PRICE
    1       A      10
    1       B      20
    1       C      70
    ...
```

And I need to make an SQL INSERT to include a new one:

```
      TBNID PRODUCT  PRICE
        2       D      80
        2       F      40
        2       G      30
```

My new table data is in Excel file.

How could be an SQL Statement to accomplish it? How can I convert the excel table so I can plug the data into the SQL statement ?

```
INSERT INTO Table_Product (TBNID,PRODUCT,PRICE) values ... ?
```

Comment: It this a one shot operation or something you are going to do several times ?

Comment: Hi ! I will do it not frequently but  at least twice a month

Comment: well in this case, you can save your excel as csv an use a command line tool like isql or fsql http://mujweb.cz/iprenosil/interbase/fsql.htm to insert

Comment: if you want to have something build into the excel file, you can do a quick vba macro which would read an area of a sheet, generate the insert, connect to the db and run inserts

Comment: humm, so I need to create a code to generate an insert for every row on my excel data ? so If I have 100 rows in my excel , I have to create 100 inserts , Is that correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

=" INSERT INTO Table_Product (TBNID, PRODUCT , PRICE) values ('"&H2&"','"&I2&"','"&J2&"') ;"

just change the Cell locations then drag down.

Comment: Hi, you mean , I need to do it in Excel first and then SQL ?

Comment: Yes, that will get the value based on cell locations and it will generate the script. If u have 100 records just drag down it will auto populate. Copy+paste it in ur DB then commit the script.

Comment: I got your idea. I didn't know  this trick on spreadsheets. It worked. Thanks a lot !